# Why is the maximum length of a scheduler chain step name 24 bytes?

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I'm trying to create a chain step that's 30 bytes long. It is failing.

Set-up:

```
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_scheduler.create_program(
  3         program_name => lpad('A', 30, 'A')
  4       , program_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
  5       , program_action => 'begin null; end;'
  6         );
  7      dbms_scheduler.create_chain('CHAIN_NAME');
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Creating the chain step:

```
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step(
  3          chain_name => 'CHAIN_NAME'
  4        , step_name => lpad('A', 30, 'B')
  5        , program_name => lpad('A', 30, 'A')
  6          );
  7  end;
  8  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27465: invalid value BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA for attribute step_name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 5057
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 1760
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 1786
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I have a byte-semantic database.

Describing DBA_SCHEDULER_CHAIN_STEPS the maximum length of a STEP_NAME is 128 bytes, i.e. 32 4-byte unicode characters:

```
SQL> desc dba_scheduler_chain_steps;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------------
 OWNER                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 CHAIN_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 STEP_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 ...
```

If I look at the definition of DBA_SCHEDULER_CHAIN_STEPS then the STEP_NAME column comes from SYS.SCHEDULER$_STEP.VAR_NAME. The definition of this column is:

```
SQL> select data_type, data_length, char_length, char_used
  2    from dba_tab_columns
  3   where owner = 'SYS'
  4     and table_name = 'SCHEDULER$_STEP'
  5     and column_name = 'VAR_NAME';

DATA_TYPE DATA_LENGTH CHAR_LENGTH C
--------- ----------- ----------- -
VARCHAR2          128         128 B
```

In other words, the maximum size of the object name is 128 bytes (32 Unicode characters).

[Section 29.2 *"About Scheduler Objects and Their Naming"*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12381) of the Oracle Database Administrators Guide says

> Scheduler objects follow the naming rules for database objects exactly and share the SQL namespace with other database objects.

[In other words](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129)

> Names must be from 1 to 30 bytes long...

However, if I create a chain step with a name 24 bytes long and one with a name 25 bytes long the 24 byte name will succeed and the 25 byte will fail

```
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step(
  3          chain_name => 'CHAIN_NAME'
  4        , step_name => lpad('A', 24, 'B')
  5        , program_name => lpad('A', 30, 'A')
  6          );
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2      dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step(
  3          chain_name => 'CHAIN_NAME'
  4        , step_name => lpad('A', 25, 'B')
  5        , program_name => lpad('A', 30, 'A')
  6          );
  7  end;
  8  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27465: invalid value BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA for attribute step_name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 5057
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 1760
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 1786
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

:-(

Why? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MoS Doc ID 2246248.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2246248.1):

> This restriction of DBMS_SCHEDULER.define_chain_step attribute “step_name”  is explicitly coded and confirmed by development.
>
> -- Attribute 'step_name' cannot be longer than 24 characters or contain '.'

That document only refers to 11.2.0.3, but it's still throwing the error in 12.1 and 12.2.

That doesn't really explain *why*, but it's sort of documented... just not in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Alex. That doesn't bring back my afternoon but hopefully it saves someone else's!